# How do I make useState hook work with my function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, react-hooks

I am trying to execute a function to update a setState but it as well needs other state to load first.

```js
    const [chatsIds, setChatsIds] = useState([]);
    const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getChatsIds();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        getChats();
    }, [chats]);
```

the "getChats" needs the value from "chatsIds" but when the screen is loaded the value isn't , only when i reload the app again it gets the value.

Here are the functions :

```js
    const getChatsIds = async () => {
        const ids = await getDoc(userRef, "chats");
        setChatsIds(ids);
    }

    const getChats = async () => {
        const chatsArr = [];

        chatsIds.forEach(async (id) => {
            const chat = await getDoc(doc(db, "Chats", id));
            chatsArr.push(chat);
            console.log(chatsArr);
        });

        setChats(chatsArr);
    }
```

I've tried with the useEffect and useLayoutEffect hooks, with promises and async functions, but i haven't found what i'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `useEffect` hook dependency. It should depends on `chatsIds` not chats.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getChats();
}, [chatsIds]);
```

Which mean fetching `chatsIds` should depend on first mount and fetching `chats` should depend on if `chatsIds` is chnaged.

Comment: I would probably pass in `chatsIds` as an argument to `getChats` too to make it explicit.

Comment: That's an good idea too @Andy

Comment: I tried what you said but **still it doesn't seem to work :(**, the chatsIds is depending on first mount and now **i changed the chats to be depending on chats ids**, but when i try to console.log the chats to test it in another useffect depending on the chats **it returns an empty array**

Comment: Did your chatsArr variable gets alll the value?

Comment: No, they get no value, idk if maybe there is an easier or different way to do this

Comment: That means the problem is in the firebase calls

Answer (score 1):

You simply change the `useEffect` hook to like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getChatsIds();
}, [chatsIds]);
```

Comment: I tried what you said but **still it doesn't seem to work :(**, the chatsIds is depending on first mount and now **i changed the chats to be depending on chats ids**, but when i try to console.log the chats to test it in another useffect depending on the chats **it returns an empty array** idk why :(

Answer (score 0):

I Think getChat() is depend on chatIds...

so you use useEffect with chatIds on dependency

```
const [chatsIds, setChatsIds] = useState([]);
const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getChatsIds();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    getChats(chatsIds);
}, [chatsIds]);

const getChatsIds = async () => {
    const ids = await getDoc(userRef, "chats");
    setChatsIds(ids);
}

const getChats = async (chatsIds) => {
    const chatsArr = [];

    chatsIds.forEach(async (id) => {
        const chat = await getDoc(doc(db, "Chats", id));
        chatsArr.push(chat);
        console.log(chatsArr);
    });

    setChats(chatsArr);
}
```